# is there a `docker up` command, like `vagrant up`?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a docker command which works like the `vagrant up` command?

I'd like to use the arangodb docker image and provide a Dockerfile for my team without forcing my teammates to get educated on the details of its operation, it should 'just work'. Within the the project root, I would expect the database to start and stop with a standard docker command. Does this not exist? If so, why not?

Comment: `vagrant up` can be Docker backed; `docker-compose up` could be what you're looking for; writing your own `start-arangdo-db` script might be the answer.  What have you already found and tried, and what specific problems are you encountering?

Comment: I'm using a shell script which contains `docker run -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD="" -p 8529:8529 arangodb`. This is an okay solution, but not amazing. Vagrant really does it right, their docs are straight to the point, adding a VM to a project takes seconds, the commands are easy to remember and easy to type. Docker, on the other hand, hides simplicity under many layers of documentation complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Compose could do it.

- `docker-compose up` builds image, creates container and starts it.
- `docker-compose stop` stops the container.
- `docker-compose start` restarts the container.
- `docker-compose down` stops the container and removes image and the container.

With Docker compose file you can configure the ArangoDB (expose ports, volume mapping for db initialisation, etc.). Place the compose file to the project root, and run the up command.

Comment: And this works with preexisting images from docker hub? Can I prevent removal of the image? I assume this would destroy all the data, and means the database has to be re-downloaded and reinstalled each time the developer decides to stop and start.

Comment: (1) Yes, using an `image:` directive; (2) no; (3) either Docker Compose can manage the volumes holding the data or you can point it at host directories, and if you're trying to store data long-term in ephemeral containers it _will_ get lost.

Comment: Instead of `docker-compose down` you can use `docker-compose stop` and then `docker-compose start`.

Comment: I'm going to try all the suggestions now and then I'll mark an answer.

Comment: @RikuJ.K. , would appreciate it if you would add mention of `docker-compose stop` for future readers. Thanks for the answer.